# NHibernate Event when data loaded using CreateCriteria

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

what event is fired when data loaded using CreateCriteria? i want to modify the data behavior before it is returned by CreateCriteria.

im not lucky to find any documentation about Event system.
i have tried **IPostCollectionRecreateEventListener** but i found that the **OnPostRecreateCollection** is never called.

please anyone can provide me a good documentation on this? or have anyone success on making this? or is there any way to solve my problem?

I Used NHibernate 2.1.2, and Fluent NHibernate

Best Regards.

Kin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use transformers for that purpose.

It's easy, you only need to implement `IResultTransformer`.